# NetLogo: setup-patches created after Tools -> Halt is used?

Tags: debugging, netlogo, halt

I my model I have several version of how my world should look like. I implemented this as "chooser" including choices:
"single_tree"
"clustered". My world is 501 * 501 patches.

When I run `setup` of my both variations, they are not created until I press Tools -> "Halt".

I don't really understand why because on my working model this works fine. Also when I run this "world variations" with basic paramaters - just with [set pcolor ...].

Please what can be bad in my model or what am I doing wrong?

here is the working example - works fine:

```
to setup-patches   ; define patchy landscape      
  ask patches [    
    ; Single tree
    ; -------------------------
    if world = "single_tree" [ 
      set pcolor green 
]

    ; Clustered trees
    ; -------------------------
    if world = "clustered" [
      set pcolor red
]    
end
```

here is little bit more complicated code but I don't see any reason for taking so long time for dispaying..

```
to setup-patches   ; define patchy landscape  
  ask patches [
    ; Single tree
    ; -------------------------
    if world = "single_tree" [  
     ask patches with [pxcor mod 50 = 0 and pycor mod 50 = 0] [
        set pcolor red
      ] 
    ]
    ; Clustered trees
    ; -------------------------
    if world = "clustered" [
       ask patch 0 0 [
         ask patches in-radius (2.99 * Grid) with [pxcor mod Grid = 0 and pycor mod Grid = 0] [
           set pcolor red
         ]
       ] 
;        ; determine cluster size
        ask patches with [pcolor = red] [
            ask patches in-radius radius [
              set pcolor yellow
            ]
          ]
    ]
end
```

I really appreciate any suggestions and thank you a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I used too many times "`ask patches`" to "`ask patches`" to do something...

the fixed code is here - with `ask patches` only once per `if` statement:

```
to setup-patches
    if world = "single_tree" [ 
      ask patches with [pxcor mod 50 = 0 and pycor mod 50 = 0] [
        set pcolor red
      ]
    ]
    if world = "clustered" [
      ask patch 0 0 [ ask patches in-radius (2.99 * Grid) with [pxcor mod Grid = 0 and pycor mod Grid = 0] [
          set pcolor red
      ]
      ]
      ask patches with [pcolor = red] [
        ask patches in-radius 5 [
          set pcolor yellow
        ]
      ]
    ]

end
```